# Blender 2.8 - Edge info and Face info

Tags: blender

I cannot find the location for the button that turns on length and angle for Faces and Edges. It used to be in the properties tab (N) but now it's not.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2.93**

[image]

You can find the Face/Edge info here:

```
3D Viewport (shift + F5) > Edit Mode (Tab) > Overlays Button (in topbar)
```

After clicking **Overlays** button in top bar (of 3D Viewport) scroll down (mouse over the down arrow) in popup and you can toggle Edge/Face angle or length below the **Measurement** section

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vgtM.png)

Comment: It appears to have been moved in 2.9 versions, I can't find it in 2.92 anymore.

Comment: It is still there. Pls refer updated screenshot, @Daniklad